# How to get rid of exception 80000003?

Tags: delphi

When I run my program (admittedly, it was built in debug mode), I get an error "External exception 80000003".

According to [Win32 Exception/Access Violation Errors](http://www.support.tabs3.com/main/R10309.htm) it means `0x80000003  EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT    A breakpoint was encountered.`

However, there are no breakpoints set in the IDE and I am running it outside of the IDE.

Yes, I have the correct executable. I deleted all breakpoints, cleaned my project and built it afresh, but still that dialog box. I even deleted the .exe, built again, saw it appear where expected. Verified the timestamp on the .exe.  I added a message box to FromCreate() and saw that, plus "External exception 80000003".

How do I make that go away (building in debug mode)?

---

D'oh!!  It was old code and I forgot that I actually had coded this in one error condition `asm int 3 end;` of course, that signals a breakpoint to the IDE (or to Windows, if the IDE is not running, hence the error box). Apologies for time wasting.

Comment: Totally understandable. I have been bitten by similar things myself.  And I have left `raise exception.create("todo write this code")` in code that I thought I was finished writing too.

Comment: +1 Thanks, @warren. Good to know that even the experts are fallible ;-)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A breakpoint is essentially a machine level instruction (opcode?) that causes the CPU processing to pause and an exception type signal raised. This is usually picked up by the OS and then onto some user process like a debugger or simillar.

When I've had this it's nearly always been when my code as jumped into some data space. I say nearly always as I've hardcoded breakpoints into code accidently when debugging some nightmares occasionally too (!).

Edit: As @Ken White says int 3 (the breakpoint interrupt) is the one I used to hard code :-)

First thing I would do is get a stack trace and work backwords.

Comment: A good point (+1), and highly likely with my C code :-)  but surely less likely with Delphi?  Still, I will try commenting out code, bit by bit, or add more message boxes & see which two this error appears between to help me locate it. Thanks

Comment: I've not used Deplhi but since it's not managed code I would always assume I can jump places if I use the equivalent of function pointers.

Comment: Delphi is basically Pascal. While it can have pointers, you have to jump through hoops to use them - and I don't. That's why I think it unlikely that my cod eis jumping to the data segment (besides which, it continues to run fine after that message).

Comment: +1, You can also check for `int 3` in your code. An old trick, possible to do since Delphi supports inline assembly, prior to having data breakpoints and debugging long-running code, was to put something like `if <SomeCondition> then asm int 3 end;`. It worked great (and I still use it occasionally because it's actually quicker to set up than a data BP), and will cause this problem if you then forget to remove it and run outside the debugger.

Comment: `int 3` is opcode 0xCC (or $CC Delphi hex style). http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_(x86_instruction)#INT_3

Comment: Ken, would it help if I used this?    procedure DebugBreak();
begin
  if FindWindow('TAppBuilder', Nil) <> 0 then     // is IDE running ?
     asm int 3 end;
end;

Comment: Just wanted to add that some frameworks or libraries might have this included (if, for example, they are in debug mode). E.g. Unreal engine's "check" function ends up calling __debugbreak() on windows which ends up being int 3 opcode. (and that's how i've arrived here)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/intrinsics/debugbreak?view=msvc-170

Comment: @Nande - agreed!