# ExitWindowsEx - External exception 80000003

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to get rid of exception 80000003?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927877/how-to-get-rid-of-exception-80000003)

to force the PC shutdown by code, we use the function `ExitWindowsEx` in Delphi 7
It woks well but on a PC of one of our user,
`ExitWindowsEx` triggers an exception :  "**External exception 80000003**"

Pc is : Windows 7 x64 Service Pack 1 build 7601

Why that ?

Comment: You have a breakpoint somewhere. A call to `DbgBreakPoint` or an `int 3` in an `asm` block.

Comment: No. I don't have any Breakpoints in the code.

Comment: The system which is raising `STATUS_BREAKPOINT`, `0x80000003` clearly disagrees with you.

Comment: Is it possible that the end-user add breakpoints (for reverse engineering) ?

Comment: Not likely. Which process raises this error? Is it your process or one that is running on the machine that is being shutdown? A JIT debugger should be able to help locate the problem.

Comment: It is my process. Our app uses madexcept to track bug on user's PC

Comment: Well something is throwing `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` and only someone who can run the code can work out what is throwing it. What more can we do for you?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17757/discussion-between-user382591-and-david-heffernan)

Comment: Some API functions have their own internal breakpoints left over from Microsoft's own development.

Comment: I have to disagree with the possible duplicate. This is clearly something related to a call to Windows API and specific to one particular user account of one particular computer. I do however also think a little bit of code would be helpful in a question like this.

Comment: @Jerry You cannot conclude that. You don't know whether or not ExitWindowsEx returns before or after the STATUS_BREAKPOINT. I'll bet that the API call returns and that it's the subsequent code that signals. Most likely the breakpoint is in user code.