# GDB Error appears while debugging OMNET++ simulation

Tags: c++, gdb, omnet++

I am working on OMNET++ project called [Exfogsim](https://github.com/rtqayyum/ExFogSim) and there is no problem when I run the simulation with (Run), but when I am trying to Debug it the following error appears:

[image: Error Msg]

with the following error

> Error with command: gdb --version
> Cannot run program "gdb": Launching failed

Answer (score 0):

Your simulation was terminated with exit code: -2147483645. The hex representation of this number is: `0x80000003`. So try search how to deal with the Windows exception `0x80000003`, for example take a look at [that one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11927877/how-to-get-rid-of-exception-80000003).